# php engine to let developers login to a plesk panel account, without knowing the real username or password

Tags: php, panel, plesk

My idea was to create a curl script server side, that uses the credentials for logging in, then grab the session ID "PHPSESSID" and share it with developers.
Everything was working perfectly, but plesk is refusing the shared session and signed the developers out for a reason that i can't understand.
Any idea on how to solve this issue, or other suggestions would be great.

Thank you

Comment: The thing you are trying to do it is named session spoofing and is a security issue. So is resonable for plesk not allowing you to connect that way.

Comment: Can't get your idea. Maybe use additional plesk admins accounts?